# Add Woocommerce free product to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am running a Woocommerce store which is also offer free product (_regular_price = 0). Customer have to choose quantity and add it to cart and place order to receive the product. But it isn't how Woocommerce works, it hide add to cart link of all products with price = 0. and doesn't display them in cart page. Is there any hook or solution to solve this problem?
thank you

Comment: "I don't want these product is offered at cart page." Sorry, I don't understand. Can you re-word this?

Comment: Sorry. I mean I want them to add free product as normal product but offer them at cart page.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want customer should buy any specific product then inside product setting there  is option where you can restrict purchase of product to specific tgpe of user say customer,  editor, author.

[product setting link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/catalog-visibility-options/)

Comment: Hi, I just want to display free product as normal product. User can add it to cart.

Comment: go through the link it might help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109409/woocommerce-hide-add-to-cart-on-free-products